# Nodes from a website are not scraping the content

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have tried to scrape the content of a news website ('titles', 'content', etc) but the nodes I am using do not return the content.

I have tried different nodes/tags, but none of them seem to be working. I have also used the SelectorGadget without any result. I have used the same strategy for scraping other websites and it has worked with no issues.

## Here is an example of trying to get the 'content'

```
library(rvest)

url_test <- read_html('https://lasillavacia.com/silla-llena/red-de-la-paz/historia/las-disidencias-son-fruto-de-anos-de-division-interna-de-las-farc') 
content_test <- html_text(html_nodes(url_test, ".article-body-mt-5"))
```

I have also tried using the `xpath` instead of the `css class` with no results.

## Here is an example of trying to get the 'date'

```
content_test <- html_text(html_nodes(url_test, ".article-date"))
```

Even if I try to scrape all the `<h>`from the website page, for example, I do also get `character(0)`

What can be the problem? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the data is actually returned in the raw HTML the server sends, and not loaded later by javascript on the page? `rvest` will not execute any javascript code.

Comment: I am not really sure. I was wondering if perhaps the content of the website is dynamically loaded. How can I find out if that is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since the content is loaded by javascript to the page, I used RSelenium to scrape the data and it worked

```
library(RSelenium)

#Setting the remote browser
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",
                                 port = 4444L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

url_test <- 'https://lasillavacia.com/silla-llena/red-de-la-paz/historia/las-disidencias-son-fruto-de-anos-de-division-interna-de-las-farc'

remDr$navigate(url_test)

#Checking if the website page is loaded 
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

#Getting the content
content_test <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = '.article-date')
content_test <-  sapply(content_test, function(x){x$getElementText()})

> content_test
[[1]]
[1] "22 de Septiembre de 2018"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. Your css selector is wrong. It should have been:

   ```
   ".article-body.mt-5"
   ```
2. The data is dynamically loaded and returned as json. You can find the endpoint in the network tab. No need for overhead of using selenium.

   ```
   library(jsonlite)

   data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/68077&_format=hal_json')
   ```

`body` is html so you could use html parser. The following is a simple text dump. You would refine with node selection.

```
library(rvest)

read_html(data[[1]]$body) %>% html_text()
```